# .htaccess absolute block using BrowserMatchNoCase

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Hi im trying to get some basic rules in htaccess working but not having much luck.

At the top of my file I want to block certain IP's and certain user agents so I have

```
## block specific IPs
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from 62.210.122.209
Deny from 109.184.114.247

## stop requests with user agent that includes these texts
BrowserMatchNoCase "xyz" bad_bot
Deny from env=bad_bot
```

this works fine on its own however I also need to stop all php scripts being accessed except for index.php and index2.php

```
## stop all php files from being accessed
<Files *.php>    
deny from all    
</Files>    
## except for index and index2
<Files ~ "^index(2)?\.php$">    
allow from all    
</Files>
```

but once I add this I get partial access to the site even with my user agent containing xyz

/index.php is blocked
but
/administrator/index.php is still open to me

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer .. simply use the environment variable setup in the first part to deny access under the files directive for index.php in the second.